# Do Angular template functions get called whenever the UI updates?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material

I wrote [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-hide-columns?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), and I want to make sure I understand the dynamics correctly.

In it whenever one of the checkboxes is selected it causes the corresponding `merge` of the observable checkbox events to trigger.

The trigger causes the redefinition of an array of instances that say whether a material table columns should be hidden or not.

The component also has this method that defines the material table columns:

```
  getDisplayedColumns():string[] {
    return this.columnDefinitions.filter(cd=>!cd.hide).map(cd=>cd.def);
  }
```

IIUC the reason that method gets called is that it gets called any time the UI is updated.  In other words Angular Change detection triggers it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Every click or another event in the UI tries to call getDisplayedColumns once and again because it is a method in the html. You have to avoid that, setting a class property with this columns when it has loaded.

Look my corrections:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-hide-columns-owzmtl?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Good point.  I had a feeling that maybe it was not a good idea :).  The new demo has this error - any idea on how to fix: ERROR
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'columns: undefined'. Current value: 'columns: id,description

Comment: Yes, I  updated the stackblitz. The getDisplayedColumns must be placed first in the constructor and the subscription.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is called from the template for every **change detection cycle.** The change detection mechanism tries to find any changes in the model of the component and then re-render changed parts.

But you can manage how the change detection mechanism works with your component by setting the change detection strategy.

### Change detection strategies

By default change detection is launched for many reasons - clicks, scrolling, or other async events. Hence the method can be invoked for hundreds/thousands of times.

But you can use `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your component. The change detection mechanism checks changes only if `@Input()` properties have changed.

But it is only half of the solution...

### Avoid using methods in the template

Another half - is not to use a method in the template at all and use class property there. Btw follow the same rule for **getters** as well

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns"></mat-row>
```

Everything you need is to set `this.columns` in your class when it should be really changed.

I hope it helps.